# Radial part for O(n) invariant differential operators acting on symmetric matrices ? 

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Consider the vector space of symmetric matrices. O(n) acts on it by conjugation $gMg^t$.

Question informally: consider invariant differential operators what is known about their radial parts ? 
(Is there something nice like Harish-Chandra's homomorphism ([this MO quest.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78191/)))

More precisely: a) Consider  O(n) invariant  differential operator with CONSTANT COEFFICIENTS D. It can be identified with some symmetric polynomial. Can we write down its radial part in terms of this polynom ? (In Harish-Chandra's case the answer is this polynom conjugated by the Vandermonde ([this MO quest.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78191/))).

b) Very particularly take $D=det(\partial_{ij}) $ what is its radial part ? (This operator enters
Capelly and Cayley identities).

c) If it is not with constant coefficients what can be said ?

Comment: In (a), you mean your differential operator to be $O(n)$-invariant, right?

Comment: By the way, I don't know the answer to your general question, but by my calculation the radial part of $\det(\partial_{ij})$ (aka the Monge-Ampère operator) is given by: the operator sends $f(|\cdot|^2)$ to $[2f'(|\cdot|^2)]^{n-1}[4f''(|\cdot|^2)|\cdot|^2+2f'(|\cdot|^2)]$.  Proof:  The endomorphism induced from the Hessian is $4f''(|\cdot|^2)|\cdot|^2\text{Proj}_{\cdot}+2f'(|\cdot|^2)]I$.

Comment: @Macbeth Thank you. Yes in a) I mean O(n) invariant. But I do not understand yours second comment - actually your notations is not clear for me - what do you mean by f( ) - is it the function on which radial part of D acts ?  Then something is wrong -  what you write is non-linear expression. While radial part is linear operator. May be you can write more details as answer, not as a comment ? Also you mention "Monge-Ampere" is there some relation between det(d/dx_ij) and "Monge-Ampere" ?  

Comment: Ah -- maybe I've misread your question?  My interpretation was:  operator is Monge-Ampère operator $\det(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i\partial x_j})$, on the space $\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (say).  Is your operator actually $\det(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{ij}})$, on the space $\mathcal{C}^\infty(Mat_n(\mathbb{R}))$?

Comment: @macbeth Yes my operator is on $Mat_n(R)$ it is $D=det(d/dx_{ij}) (with symmetry ij=ji). Such operators are used in Capelli and Cayley identities. Symmetric version of Capelli identity is due to Turnbull - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capelli's_identity .  

Comment: I see.  I don't know your terminology, then -- would you mind defining the "radial part" of an $O(n)$-invariant operator on [functions on] this space?  Is it the induced operator on [functions on] its space of $O(n)$-orbits?

Comment: @macbeth It is induced operator on factor Mat/O(n) (not on orbit - actually transversal to orbit). The terminology comes from standard Laplace operator in R^n  its radial part d/dr^2 + (n-1)d/dr . So here O(n) acts on R^n and Laplace is invariant operator for this action. 